# iStockPhoto Lightbox-type extension

Tags: add-on, extension

Has anyone come across an extension that will allow a user to create multiple "lightboxes" of their favourite channel entries?

I am aware of the [Solspace Favourites](http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/favorites/) module, but that only allows users to create a single list. I need the user to be able to create multiple "lightboxes" or favourites lists, as used by iStockPhoto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is also [Bookmarks](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/bookmarks) module, but it also does not allow you to create sets of bookmarks.

I would use different approach:

- create a channel named "Lightboxes" with custom field that will hold relationships with entries
- use [Safecracker](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/safecracker/index.html) to create a lighbox
- have some code that will add entries to relationships custom field in lightbox entry

Answer (score 0):

[CartThrob Wish List](http://cartthrob.com/site/product_detail/wish-list) is a little known add-on that allows you to create lists of entries.  It's a module they developed for a client of mine and then refined and added a bunch of features to.  I've never tried to use it outside of a CartThrob ecommerce site, but I don't see any reason that it should be dependent on it.  You would simply not need to take advantage of the flipside of the module, which is allowing third parties to buy items from the wish list, thereby debiting the "wanted" volume of the given entries.  But that's what immediately came to mind based on your need.

The other one that came to mind is [Joel Bradbury's Shortlist](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/shortlist) - but currently it doesn't offer multiple lists to users either. It may be something he's working on for a future release perhaps.

Comment: Wouter also made RememberMe which seems it can store entry id's to several lists. http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/remember-me